# Upgrading from MariaDB 5.3 to 5.5?

Tags: database, upgrade, mariadb

What are the steps involved in upgrading from MariaDB 5.3 to 5.5?

It's effectively the equivalent of upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5, which [entails various notes and tools](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html), yet I can't find any instructions for making the equivalent Maria upgrade.

(Not looking for a fancy live upgrade. Some downtime to backup and restore is fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always make a backup prior to performing an upgrade. Especially for a major version upgrade.

That said, I didn't run into any trouble when I upgraded. It's definitely easier than a MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 upgrade. This is partly because MariaDB 5.5 is just MariaDB 5.3 merged with MySQL 5.5.

5.3 had big under-the-hood optimizer changes. That's why it took a long time to become stable. Contrast that with the relatively short period between the first stable release of MariaDB 5.3 and the first stable release of MariaDB 5.5: all of the really hard work had already been done in 5.3.

Disclaimer: I work on the MariaDB project, so I'm pretty biased. :-)

Edit: I suppose I should mention what I actually did to upgrade... I use Ubuntu so I updated my sources.list and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That was it.

To be fair, my personal databases are quite small, and even the database behind the MariaDB Knowledge Base at http://mariadb.com/kb isn't that large, so I'm not talking about an upgrade of a multi-terabyte database with thousands of nodes or anything, just an upgrade of a few small independent servers. If you want an account of a large combination migration and upgrade, check out Wikipedia's: http://blog.wikimedia.org/2013/04/22/wikipedia-adopts-mariadb/

Comment: It's always good to hear from someone right from MariaDB project. Thanks for all the work you have put into MariaDB!

Comment: Hi dbart, thanks for taking the time! I asked a related question on ServerFault in case you want to weigh in :) http://serverfault.com/questions/648295/mariadb-should-i-upgrade-from-5-1-to-5-5-directly

Answer (score 1):

During this month, September 2013, I have written how to do a migration from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.6, although it's written in spanish. You can read it, and if you need some help, just contact me!

The link is here: http://www.manejandodatos.es/2013/09/migracion-de-mysql-5-5-a-5-6-paso-1-copias-de-seguridad/